# FullCalendar timeline vertical stacking

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I hava a fullCalendar timeline view where 3 event sources are defined.
When these events are rendered, I want these events to 'stick' in their vertical order.
Example: when no events come from source 1, all events of source 2 and 3 are 'pushed up'. I want the first event source 'bar' to stay empty so that the user can clearly see that there are no events for the first source.

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: screenshot is not working.

Comment: You can also paste the screenshot here on Stackoverflow. It is more convenient for most Stackoverflow users.

Comment: Ok, I updated the image link. Works now

Comment: I reckon you could make some sort of workaround for this using column grouping (see https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.8.0/demos/column-grouping.html for a demo) such that you divided the resource up with one grouping item for each event source, and in your event source include the custom field showing which group it should go into. It's a little bit of a hack in a way but I can't think of a better way. There's nothing by default which would separate data from different event sources in the visual way you described.